# Stormpath Express: Anyway to deactivate the surname and lastname?

Tags: stormpath

Is there anyway to note require or even activate the surname and lastname, but instate to use a username (nickname) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the surname and lastname are required.  I would work around this by supplying junk values for them, for example "first" and "last" for all accounts.

Comment: There is now an option in the Stormpath express configuration for you to disable these fields.  Stormpath will fill in a good default for you on your behalf.